# Tizen Samsung Gear S Background Service

Tags: tizen, background-service, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm attempting to create and app that would rely on a background service to monitor some of the sensors on the device and alert the user accordingly.  In tizen 2.3 it appears that this can be done by creating a tizen:service and bundling it with the app.  However all the research I've done shows that tizen 2.3 isn't available on any of the tizen wearables yet.

Are there any other ways of getting this sensor data in the background (something that works on tizen 2.2) or is there a projected date for when tizen 2.3 will be available on the Samsung Gear S?

Comment: You want to write an app, which collects sensor data even when the app goes to background(not exited), still you want to monitor/collect the sensor data. Is this your requirement/problem/question?

Comment: Not just when the app goes to background, but also when the the watch itself is dormant (screen off).  From what I've seen, the watch will suspend all apps a few minutes after the screen goes off.  I want to be able to monitor the sensors at all times and alert the user upon a change.  This is why I think I'd need to write it as a service, but this isn't available on the version of Tizen that is currently on the Gear S.

Comment: Have a look at the answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483822/start-tizen-app-at-start-up

Comment: I know that it can be done in 2.3, my problem is that the Gear S is still running 2.2.  I was wondering if there was a way to do it in 2.2 or if I'd have to wait until 2.3 found its way to the Gear S.

Comment: there is no 2.3 for wearables. 2.2 is mentioned by default in config.xml file of app wearable when you create an app. You can use wearable documentation with urls having */wearable/2.3.0/*

Answer (score 0):

Two things have to be done.
1) in config.xml of your project, go to Tizen tab and set background-support to enable
2) In your code have this line tizen.power.request("CPU", "CPU_AWAKE");

Answer (score 0):

To automatically start Service-apps, a partner level certificate is needed.

1. Tools > Certificate Manager.
2. Give any name as "Certificate profile name" > Next.
3. Choose "Create a new author certificate" > Next.
4. Fill all entries > Next.
5. Check "Privilege level", and select "Partner" > Finish.